# CustomHook -> useDispach = could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

**useReduxContext.js:24 Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a**

I have a simple custom hook and I am trying to call redux dispatch from my hook in order to organize my logic in 1 place instead call the dispatch in each component

my custom hook:

```
export function useToggle(data:any) {
  const [val, setToggle] = React.useState(data:any);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onToggle = (event: any, val: any) => {
    setToggle(val)
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    setToggle(data:any)
  },[data:any])

  return { val, onToggle };
}
```

my component that calls the hook for sure is under provider

this my componenet :

```
      <Parent
 
          >
            <Child />
            <Child2>{renderData()}</Child2>
          </Parent>
```

and inside Child 2 I have a simple function component with this code

```
  const { val, onToggle } = useToggle(data);
```

my index.ts

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App history={history} />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: You can't use useDispatch without Provider https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider

Comment: I have a provider in the root

Comment: @Freestyle09 I have updated the question , i already have Provider and I use the 'usedispach' all over the code
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App history={history} />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. I believe the only wrapper for this for now is to use old connect from react-redux.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponentName);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is needed in index.js

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './Redux/Store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```